# How to find location of error from stacktrace alone

Tags: eclipse, exception, stack-trace

If I run a java file from my IDE and an exception is thrown, a hyperlink is printed that I can use to view the line of code that threw the Exception.

However, if I run from terminal all I will get is something like this:

`at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)`

with obviously no hyperlink. How do I use the `531` to navigate to the line of code that is responsible for the error?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy/paste your stacktrace to the eclipse console. Your stacktrace will magically become clickable and will open the file in which the error occured, provided eclipse has it in its class path.

Comment: It's not readonly when it shows the log of a running java program. It becomes read only as soon as the program stops.